# angular 2 reload specific html element

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, primeng

I just need `window.location.reload()` for a specific element only.
Specifically, I have a table with many columns.

`<p-dataTable #tableRef class="invoice-datatable"></p-dataTable>`

When I click the image below, I call refreshTable method which I need it to refresh datatable only.

```
`<img role="button" id="refresh-icon" src="/assets/img/refresh.png (click)="refreshTable(tableRef)">
```

Comment: If you bind a model to the table with something like `<p-dataTable [value]="myModel">`, does the table not refresh when the model changes?

Comment: It does.But how can I implement this by clicking on the image?

Answer (score 0):

there is some method to reset the datatable as

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(DataTable) dataTableComponent: DataTable;

    // ...

    refreshTable() {
        this.dataTableComponent.reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataTable is bound to a model then you just need to update that model with whatever new data necessary when the image is clicked.

Using `.reset()` will only reset the filters, sorts, and pagination. It doesn't refresh the data, sadly.